# Regex to match all sub direcotries of a domain except one

Tags: regex

```
^(?!example.com\/checkout).*
```

I want to match the domain name and all its sub-directories `example.com/xyz` except checkout directory `example.com/checkout`

Comment: Did you consider `^example.com(?!\/checkout\/?$)(?:\/.*)?`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^example\.com\/(?:(?!checkout)[^\/])*$
```

The negated character group ensures we match everything but `/` and only if the text after the first slash starts with `checkout` (checkout2 wouldn't work either). If you want to allow checkout2 add an end anchor `$` inside the negative lookahead `^example\.com\/(?!checkout$)[^\/]*$`

Comment: dont want checkout2 only checkout